# Mac OS X: Use links to server for user's Documents & Pictures?

Tags: macos, filesystems

I'm setting up a shiny new desktop Mac. I'd rather have the Users/user_name/Documents and /Pictures be symbolic links to a server (via /Volumes).

Any downside/problems/tips with doing this?

Comment: Are you using Time Machine? And I doubt it matters, but just in case: are you using File Vault?

Comment: @Arjan What are your concerns about TM?

Comment: @Daniel, I don't know and you're right: I should have made clear I was just trying to improve the question, *if* applicable. I just figured it *might* matter to those who answer the question. (Like: I know TM can backup external drives. But I don't know if it does that automatically? And I surely don't know if it matters if external drives are mapped into the user's home folder? Or how things works while restoring stuff, especially while doing a fresh installation with a user's account from a TM backup?)

Comment: Time Machine and File Vault are good questions. At this point, I'm not planning to use either--the server has raid disks. (Yes, I know that's not the same as backups.)

Comment: @Arjan Makes sense. But in those cases, use of FV is probably important information, since the home folder only is backed up when the FV disk image isn't mounted, and therefore just a bunch of band files.